# Date column changed to Date and Time Column not showing times

Tags: 2007, microsoft-access

I have several lists that need to be changed from Date Only to Date and Time in order to merge the lists in Access and generate reports. I changed the radio button on the column to Date and Time, and it displays as 12:00:00 in sharepoint, but when importing into Access, I still only get Date data.

Testing:

1. I modified one item from the list from default 12:00:00, and it now shows up with the time included, but the rest of the items still show up with no time at all in Access.
2. I modified a different item but did not touch the date/time column, and it does not have a time in Access still.

My guess is, Sharepoint doesn't have a value associated with the time, and it has a rule that fills in 12:00:00 when it doesn't have a value associated with times but needs one.

-> Is there any way to get the time part of this column pushed into existence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there isn't a way that isn't modifying each item in the list. Sigh.